# C++ valarray vs. vector

Tags: c++, stl, stdvector, std, valarray

I like vectors a lot. They're nifty and fast. But I know this thing called a valarray exists. Why would I use a valarray instead of a vector? I know valarrays have some syntactic sugar, but other than that, when are they useful?

Comment: Just was pondering this the other day, too. As far as I know, it's really just as specialized math vector.

Comment: Doesn't valarray do expression templates?

Comment: Physicist Ulrich Mutze provides a use-case for `valarray` [here](http://goo.gl/QVDJKq) and [here](http://goo.gl/ja7q8d)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Valarrays (value arrays) are intended to bring some of the speed of Fortran to C++. You wouldn't make a valarray of pointers so the compiler can make assumptions about the code and optimise it better. (The main reason that Fortran is so fast is that there is no pointer type so there can be no pointer aliasing.)

Valarrays also have classes which allow you to slice them up in a reasonably easy way although that part of the standard could use a bit more work. Resizing them is destructive and <s>they lack iterators</s> they have iterators since C++11.

So, if it's numbers you are working with and convenience isn't all that important use valarrays. Otherwise, vectors are just a lot more convenient.

Comment: They are not designed to avoid pointers. C++11 defines begin() and end() in valarray that return iterators to them

Comment: @user2023370: that's why so many Fortran users prefer Fortran 77. :)

Answer (score 188):

`valarray` is kind of an orphan that was born in the wrong place at the wrong time. It's an attempt at optimization, fairly specifically for the machines that were used for heavy-duty math when it was written -- specifically, vector processors like the Crays.

For a vector processor, what you generally wanted to do was apply a single operation to an entire array, then apply the next operation to the entire array, and so on until you'd done everything you needed to do.

Unless you're dealing with fairly small arrays, however, that tends to work poorly with caching. On most modern machines, what you'd generally prefer (to the extent possible) would be to load part of the array, do all the operations on it you're going to, then move on to the next part of the array.

`valarray` is also supposed to eliminate any possibility of aliasing, which (at least theoretically) lets the compiler improve speed because it's more free to store values in registers. In reality, however, I'm not at all sure that any real implementation takes advantage of this to any significant degree. I suspect it's rather a chicken-and-egg sort of problem -- without compiler support it didn't become popular, and as long as it's not popular, nobody's going to go to the trouble of working on their compiler to support it.

There's also a bewildering (literally) array of ancillary classes to use with valarray. You get `slice`, `slice_array`, `gslice` and `gslice_array` to play with pieces of a `valarray`, and make it act like a multi-dimensional array. You also get `mask_array` to "mask" an operation (e.g. add items in x to y, but only at the positions where z is non-zero). To make more than trivial use of `valarray`, you have to learn a lot about these ancillary classes, some of which are pretty complex and none of which seems (at least to me) very well documented.

Bottom line: while it has moments of brilliance, and can do some things pretty neatly, there are also some very good reasons that it is (and will almost certainly remain) obscure.

Edit (eight years later, in 2017): Some of the preceding has become obsolete to at least some degree. For one example, Intel has implemented an optimized version of valarray for their compiler. It uses the Intel Integrated Performance Primitives (Intel IPP) to improve performance. Although the exact performance improvement undoubtedly varies, a quick test with simple code shows around a 2:1 improvement in speed, compared to identical code compiled with the "standard" implementation of `valarray`.

So, while I'm not entirely convinced that C++ programmers will be starting to use `valarray` in huge numbers, there are least some circumstances in which it can provide a speed improvement.

Comment: Is it specifically disallowed to store arbitrary object types inside valarray?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Yes -- there's a (rather long) list of restrictions at [Numeric.Requirements]. For just a couple examples, all abstract classes and exceptions are prohibited. It also requires equivalence between (for example) copy construction and a sequence of default construction followed by assignment.

Comment: @JerryCoffin sheesh that's scary. we promise that we wont use it.

Comment: I wouldn't decide that based on fear. I'd decide it based on whether you need to store elements that use features it prohibits.

Comment: Truly is amazing how many upvotes you got here.  Most of the information is vague and just incorrect.

Comment: @annoying_squid: If you have more specific and (you believe) accurate information to add, please feel free to add an answer showing it. As it stands right now, your comment doesn't seem to add any useful information though.

Comment: Are the stuff mentioned here still true after all these years? Are there reasons it isn't depreciated yet?

Comment: I read similar things, e.g.lacking expression templates and perhaps sbo or fixed size valarray. I hope that the standard committee fixes this thing since in itself there is room for such a specialized container. another wish would be that Visual Studio adds some SSE optimizations for arithmetic operations on valarrays.

Comment: @gast128: I'd guess most compilers can vectorize (at least some) operations on `valarray`s. The "problem" is that they can probably do the same vectorizing for similar operations on something like a `std::vector` just about as well, so there's rarely much efficiency gain from using a `valarray`. To gain much, somebody's almost certainly going to have to go beyond generic optimizations that apply equally to other code.

Answer (score 44):

During the standardization of C++98, valarray was designed to allow some sort of fast mathematical computations. However, around that time Todd Veldhuizen invented expression templates and created [blitz++](https://github.com/blitzpp/blitz/wiki/), and similar template-meta techniques were invented, which made valarrays pretty much obsolete before the standard was even released. IIRC, the original proposer(s) of valarray abandoned it halfway into the standardization, which (if true) didn't help it either.

ISTR that the main reason it wasn't removed from the standard is that nobody took the time to evaluate the issue thoroughly and write a proposal to remove it.

*Please keep in mind, however, that all this is vaguely remembered hearsay.* Take this with a grain of salt and hope someone corrects or confirms this.

Comment: expression templates can be equally credited to Vandevoorde too, right ?

Comment: @Nikos: Not that I know of. I could be wrong, though. What do you have in favor of that reading?

Comment: it's mentioned in the book "C++ Templates - The complete guide", I think it's generally accepted that they both invented them [independently](http://collaboration.cmc.ec.gc.ca/science/rpn/biblio/ddj/Website/articles/CUJ/2003/0306/cuj0306becker/).

Answer (score 30):

> I know valarrays have some syntactic sugar

I have to say that I don't think `std::valarrays` have much in way of syntactic sugar.  The syntax is different, but I wouldn't call the difference "sugar."  The API is weird.  The section on `std::valarray`s in *The C++ Programming Language* mentions this unusual API and the fact that, since `std::valarray`s are expected to be highly optimized, any error messages you get while using them will probably be non-intuitive.

Out of curiosity, about a year ago I pitted `std::valarray` against `std::vector`.  I no longer have the code or the precise results (although it shouldn't be hard to write your own).  Using GCC I *did* get a little performance benefit when using `std::valarray` for simple math, but not for my implementations to calculate standard deviation (and, of course, standard deviation isn't that complex, as far as math goes).  <strike>I suspect that operations on each item in a large `std::vector` play better with caches than operations on `std::valarray`s.</strike> (**NOTE**, following advice from [musiphil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/424632/musiphil), I've managed to get almost identical performance from `vector` and `valarray`).

**In the end, I decided to use `std::vector` while paying close attention to things like memory allocation and temporary object creation.**

---

Both `std::vector` and `std::valarray` store the data in a contiguous block.  However, they access that data using different patterns, and more importantly, the API for `std::valarray` encourages different access patterns than the API for `std::vector`.

For the standard deviation example, at a particular step I needed to find the collection's mean and the difference between each element's value and the mean.

For the `std::valarray`, I did something like:

```
std::valarray<double> original_values = ... // obviously I put something here
double mean = original_values.sum() / original_values.size();
std::valarray<double> temp(mean, original_values.size());
std::valarray<double> differences_from_mean = original_values - temp;
```

I may have been more clever with `std::slice` or `std::gslice`.  It's been over five years now.

For `std::vector`, I did something along the lines of:

```
std::vector<double> original_values = ... // obviously, I put something here
double mean = std::accumulate(original_values.begin(), original_values.end(), 0.0) / original_values.size();

std::vector<double> differences_from_mean;
differences_from_mean.reserve(original_values.size());
std::transform(original_values.begin(), original_values.end(), std::back_inserter(differences_from_mean), std::bind1st(std::minus<double>(), mean));
```

Today I would certainly write that differently.  If nothing else, I would take advantage of C++11 lambdas.

It's obvious that these two snippets of code do different things.  For one, the `std::vector` example doesn't make an intermediate collection like the `std::valarray` example does.  However, I think it's fair to compare them because the differences are tied to the differences between `std::vector` and `std::valarray`.

When I wrote this answer, I suspected that subtracting the value of elements from two `std::valarray`s (last line in the `std::valarray` example) would be less cache-friendly than the corresponding line in the `std::vector` example (which happens to also be the last line).

**It turns out, however, that**

```
std::valarray<double> original_values = ... // obviously I put something here
double mean = original_values.sum() / original_values.size();
std::valarray<double> differences_from_mean = original_values - mean;
```

**Does the same thing as the `std::vector` example, and has almost identical performance.  In the end, the question is which API you prefer.**

Comment: I cannot think of any reason why a `std::vector` would play better with caches than a `std::valarray`; they both allocate a single contiguous block of memory for their elements.

Comment: @musiphil My response got too long for a comment, so I've updated the answer.

Comment: For your `valarray` example above, you didn't have to construct a `temp` `valarray` object, but you could have just done `std::valarray<double> differences_from_mean = original_values - mean;`, and then the cache behavior should be similar to that of the `vector` example. (By the way, if `mean` is really `int`, not `double`, you may need `static_cast<double>(mean)`.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to clean up the `valarray`.  I'll need to see if that improves the performance.  As for `mean` being `int`: that was a mistake.  I originally wrote the example up using `int`s, and then realized that the `mean` would then be very far from the real mean because of truncation.  But I missed a few needed changes on my first round of edits.

Comment: @musiphil You're right; that change brought the sample code to almost identical performance.

Comment: Not sure how this answer got so many upvotes as it essentially conveys no new and important information.  The example is overly simplistic and doesn't play to valarrays strength, so drawing conclusions from it is a mistake.

Answer (score 24):

valarray was supposed to let some FORTRAN vector-processing goodness rub off on C++.  Somehow the necessary compiler support never really happened.

The  Josuttis books contains some interesting (somewhat disparaging) commentary on valarray ([here](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=n9VEG2Gp5pkC&lpg=PA547&ots=Rdj8kmcaTT&dq=Josuttis%20valarray&pg=PA547#v=onepage&q=&f=false) and [here](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=EotSAwuBkJoC&lpg=PA342&ots=iwL1E65kdd&dq=Josuttis%20valarray&pg=PA342#v=onepage&q=&f=false)).

However, Intel now seem to be revisiting valarray in their recent compiler releases (e.g see [slide 9](http://sc.tamu.edu/help/intel/tutorial/compiler_2.pdf)); this is an interesting development given that their 4-way SIMD SSE instruction set is about to be joined by 8-way AVX and 16-way Larrabee instructions and in the interests of portability it'll likely be much better to code with an abstraction like valarray than (say) intrinsics.

Answer (score 23):

I found one good usage for valarray.
It's to use valarray just like numpy arrays.

```
auto x = linspace(0, 2 * 3.14, 100);
plot(x, sin(x) + sin(3.f * x) / 3.f + sin(5.f * x) / 5.f);
```

[image]

We can implement above with valarray.

```
valarray<float> linspace(float start, float stop, int size)
{
    valarray<float> v(size);
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++) v[i] = start + i * (stop-start)/size;
    return v;
}

std::valarray<float> arange(float start, float step, float stop)
{
    int size = (stop - start) / step;
    valarray<float> v(size);
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++) v[i] = start + step * i;
    return v;
}

string psstm(string command)
{//return system call output as string
    string s;
    char tmp[1000];
    FILE* f = popen(command.c_str(), "r");
    while(fgets(tmp, sizeof(tmp), f)) s += tmp;
    pclose(f);
    return s;
}

string plot(const valarray<float>& x, const valarray<float>& y)
{
    int sz = x.size();
    assert(sz == y.size());
    int bytes = sz * sizeof(float) * 2;
    const char* name = "plot1";
    int shm_fd = shm_open(name, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);
    ftruncate(shm_fd, bytes);
    float* ptr = (float*)mmap(0, bytes, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);
    for(int i=0; i<sz; i++) {
        *ptr++ = x[i];
        *ptr++ = y[i];
    }

    string command = "python plot.py ";
    string s = psstm(command + to_string(sz));
    shm_unlink(name);
    return s;
}
```

Also, we need python script.

```
import sys, posix_ipc, os, struct
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sz = int(sys.argv[1])
f = posix_ipc.SharedMemory("plot1")
x = [0] * sz
y = [0] * sz
for i in range(sz):
    x[i], y[i] = struct.unpack('ff', os.read(f.fd, 8))
os.close(f.fd)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I had literally the exact same thoughts as you did when I found out about valarray today at work. I think from now on for math processing problems in c++ I will be using valarray since the code looks way simpler to under stand from a math perspective.

Answer (score 8):

The C++11 standard says:

> The valarray array classes are defined to be free of certain forms of
>   aliasing, thus allowing operations on these classes to be optimized.

See C++11 26.6.1-2.

Comment: Since I assume the Standard does define which forms, can you quote them? Also, are these implemented using coding tricks, or are they compiler-based exceptions to aliasing rules elsewhere in the language?

Answer (score 5):

With `std::valarray` you can use the standard mathematical notation like `v1 = a*v2 + v3` out of the box. This is not possible with vectors unless you define your own operators.

Answer (score 1):

std::valarray is intended for heavy numeric tasks, such as Computational Fluid Dynamics or Computational Structure Dynamics, in which you have arrays with millions, sometimes tens of millions of items, and you iterate over them in a loop with also millions of timesteps. Maybe today std::vector has a comparable performance but, some 15 years ago, valarray was almost mandatory if you wanted to write an efficient numeric solver.

Answer (score 1):

Basically `std::valarray` are vectors in a more mathematical sense that allow well defined mathematical operations like `c = a + b`, while `std::vector` are dynamic arrays. The names are just misleading.

In a vector the dimension is fixed and all its elements are restricted to variables that allow arithmetic operations and if you create one with apples, the compiler will immediately complains that apples are not variables that support arithmetic operations.

Also, mathematical functions like `sqrt()`, `log()`, `sin()`, etc. accept vectors as input and perform the operation to each element, which is great for architectures Single Instruction Multiple Data with a very large number of cores. For example, GPUs are very good working with vectors.

This is why a vector can have a much more complex memory structure. Its elements can be distributed along several nodes, while `std::vector` is basically a container with a pointer to a continuous memory.

And I still see people trying to use `std::vector` with CUDA. No sorry, despite the misleading name, you can't use `std::vector` because it is not a vector. I know, they recognize it was a historical error, but they haven't even tried to correct that mistake.