# What is the difference between std::valarray and std::array

Tags: c++, stdarray, valarray

`valarray` class look's same to `array` class, can you please explain me where would I prefer `valarray` over `array` or vice versa?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602451/c-valarray-vs-vector

Comment: It is `valarray`, not `vallaray`. They are not the same thing at all, you probably should not use `valarray` since it is so poorly thought as to render it useless. The difference between `array` and `vector` should suffice.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

- `valarray` was already in C++03, `array` is new in C++11
- `valarray` is variable length, `array` is not.
- `valarray` is designed for numeric computations and provides plenty of operations including `+`, `-`, `*`, `cos`, `sin`, etc... `array` does not.
- `valarray` has an interface to retrieve slices of the array (sub arrays), `array` does not.

Comment: while all the answers are good and each has something more I wasn't know which to accept. so thanks to all of you!.

Comment: Permit me to add a couple of links about `array` and `array` versus `vector` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15079057/arrays-vs-vectors-introductory-similarities-and-differences

Answer (score 6):

`valarray` is a dynamic data structure, whose size can change at runtime and which performs dynamic allocation. `array` is a static data structure whose size is determined at compile time (and it is also an aggregate).

Don't use `valarray`, though; just use a `vector` instead.

Comment: @zhermes: hm, maybe [check this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602451/c-valarray-vs-vector) for some background information. Essentially, standard algorithms and `vector` give you everything you need.

Answer (score 6):

The class templates related to `std::valarray<T>` are intended to support optimizations techniques known as *expression templates*. I haven't tried to do this but my understanding is that the specification doesn't quite require this and also doesn't really support this sufficiently. In general `std::valarray<T>` is a fairly specialized class and it isn't really broadly used. Also, I think the template arguments support for `std::valarray<T>` are a limited set (e.g. the numeric built-in types).

On the other `std::array<T, n>` is a fixed size array supporting, as far as possible while being fixed size, the normal container interface. Essentially, `std::array<T>` is a more convenient to use version of `T[n]`.