# Avoiding memory leak in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, global-variables

I'm beginning at coding in C++, and I recently encountered a problem that I can't really find a solution for it, because I don't understand my error.

My program is made to give the conversion in Kelvin to Celsius, but it isn't able to do it for more than 3 temperatures in a row. As soon as I pass 4, it gives me the right conversion with a memory problem (out of range?).

> Error in "xxx": Double free or corruption (out): 0x0000000001c94c40

And when I enter more than four temperatures it gives some random numbers, that are probably values of other adresses.

Here is my program.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

unsigned int NumberT {0};           //Definition of the global variables
double* Kelvin=new double[NumberT];
double* Celsius=new double[NumberT];
unsigned int i=0;


double* Conversion (double, double, unsigned int)   //Conversion function
{
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<NumberT;++i)
    {
        Celsius[i]=Kelvin[i]-273.15;
    }
    return Celsius;
}


void printTemperatures (double, double, unsigned int)   //Print function
{
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<NumberT;++i)
    {
        cout<<"The temperature is "<< Kelvin[i] <<" [K], which is "<< Celsius[i] <<" [C]"<<endl;
    }
    return;
}


int main ()                     //Main
{   
    cout<<"How many temperatures do you want to enter?"<<"\n";
    cin>>NumberT;

    cout<<"What are the temperatures?"<<"\n";
    for (unsigned int i=0;i<NumberT;++i)
    {
        cin>>Kelvin[i];
    }

    Conversion (Kelvin[i], Celsius[i], NumberT);
    printTemperatures (Kelvin[i], Celsius[i], NumberT);


    delete [] Celsius;
    delete [] Kelvin;
    return 0;
}
```

So I would be really happy to know what is wrong with my code, and why is it like this. I heard that we shouldn't use global variables, and this can maybe help me to understand why.

By the way I'm interested to have some advices on how to write a proper code with a good syntax, without having scope problems. Because I would like to learn how to write a function that is the most "universal" possible, so that I can pull it and use it in another program with other variables.

Thank you in advance for your support

P.S.: I'm using g++ as compiler and the 2011 C++ standard

Comment: `NumberT` is 0 when you do your memory allocation - move the globals and memory allocation inside `main`, read the value of `NumberT` first, and only then do the actual memory allocations. You should also format your code properly - you have a number of other errors which will become more obvious once the code is formatted.

Comment: You really should be using a `std::vector<double>` instead of `double*`.

Comment: Your arrays, that you allocated, have a size of 0. I don't remember if such an action is an undefined behavior in of itself, but trying to write data to such an array - definitively is.

Comment: You should never use `new` which will make your code much easier and memory leaks very unlikely. Stick to values, `std::vector` and if you absolutely cannot avoid it use `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Why do you not use _indentation_?

Answer (score -2):

A good habit in modern C++ is to never use manual memory management - if you see `new` or `delete` in the c++11 or later code it's a sign of code smell.

Use `std::make_shared`/`std::make_unique` instead, use `value types` and `std::move`.

See Herb Sutter's latest [talk "Leak-Freedom in C++ by default"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JfmTagWcqoE).

For your particular example

`unsigned int NumberT {0};           //Definition of the global variables
double* Kelvin=new double[NumberT];`

You create an array with 0 elements here, then you do a lot of unallocated memory overwrites and then try to free it. This won't work.

Move array allocations to AFTER you've read the `NumberT` from `std::cin` and it should improve considerably.

Next improvement would be to switch to more functional style without global variables (you don't need them).

Then switch to using `std::shared_ptr`s.

Comment: Shame `std::make_unique` doesn't exist in C++11, so you're going to have to see "`new`" in your code at least once ;)

Comment: You're still using `new` even in that which could cause a leak.  the real `std::make_unique` will not leak on failed construction.

Comment: True, but this can be fixed. I switched to c++14 so it's not a problem for me anymore.

Comment: @Berkus: Exactly; that has a `new` in it and (as Nathan points out) a broken one. This is precisely my point!

Comment: @BoundaryImposition I don't see what you imply at. `make_unique` is part of c++14 and you don't have to see any `new`, broken or not.

Comment: @Berkus: Your replacement for `make_unique` in C++11, posted in the answer above, has a `new` in it, and it is broken.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition It's an example. I do not want you to use it. JUST AN EXAMPLE. Write your own or use c++14.

Comment: @Berkus: You said you didn't understand my comment. I simply explained it. Please don't shout at me.

Comment: It does not invalidate anything I said in the post. Watch the video.

Comment: _"I do not want you to use it"_ People might use it when they see your answer; you should write a notice on it with a disclaimer so that they realise it's broken!

Comment: Are you happy now?

Answer (score -2):

Your problem is that `NumberT` is `0` when you do your memory allocation.
When you do:

```
double* Kelvin=new double[0];
```

No initialization is performed, so the pointer has indeterminate value.
Writing and reading this memory has undetermined behavior.

When you use `delete[]` on an pointer with indeterminate value your code probably will crash.

This issue is perfect for using a `vector<double>` instead of an `double[]` array, there is no reason not to use the dynamic memory handling facilities provided by this container.

Use as this example:

```
//Replace arrays with vectors
vector<double> Kelvin;
vector<double> Celsius;

//in your main to read user input
for (unsigned int i=0;i<NumberT;++i)
{
    double read;
    cin >> read;
    Kelvin.push_back(read);
}

//In your conversion function
for (std::vector<double>::iterator it = Kelvin.begin(); it != Kelvin.end(); ++it)
{
  Celsius.push_back((*it)-273.15);
}
```

Other tips:

-You dont need to declare global variables (you can declare it at the begining of your `main()`for example) and pass variables by referece, like This:

```
void Conversion (vector<double> & Kelvin, vector<double> & Celsius);
```

-When the `vector`s goes out of scope(at the end of your `main()`), they will do the `delete` work for you.

Answer (score -2):

As the other said. Your arrays initialization is the issue.
In general, since you don't know the initial size of your elements I would immediately think about vectors. In that case, you could remove the "How many elements.." and introduce an exit character or parse X separated values.

Of course, using arrays is not wrong but you have to (re)initialize them with the correct size. Thus after you get the `NumberT`. Nevertheless, for array vs vector check this [Arrays Vs Vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15079462/5202037)

I have posted an implementation using vectors but still, is based on your approach.

(NOTE!: This code is not efficient since it does a lot of vector copies and that is to not introduce new concepts. Please search on your own for arguments by reference and std::move)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<double> ToCelcius(std::vector<double> kelvinValues)   //Conversion function
{
    std::vector<double> celciusValues;
    for (auto value : kelvinValues)
    {
        celciusValues.push_back(value - 273.15);
    }
    return celciusValues;
}


void PrintTemperatures(std::vector<double> kelvinSource, std::vector<double> celsiusSource)   //Print function
{
        for (uint16_t valueIndex = 0; valueIndex < kelvinSource.size(); valueIndex++)
        {
            std::cout << "The temperature is " << kelvinSource.at(valueIndex) << " [K], which is " << celsiusSource.at(valueIndex)<< " [C]" << std::endl;
        }
}


int main()                     //Main
{
    uint16_t numberOfValues;
    std::cout << "How many temperatures do you want to enter?" << "\n";
    std::cin >> numberOfValues;

    std::cout << "What are the temperatures?" << "\n";
    std::vector<double> kelvinValues;

    double value;
    for (uint16_t i = 0; i< numberOfValues; ++i)
    {
        if (std::cin >> value) {
            kelvinValues.push_back(value);
        }
        continue;
    }
    auto celciusValues = ToCelcius(kelvinValues);
    PrintTemperatures(kelvinValues, celciusValues);

    return 0;
}
```