# Strange C++ compile error with valarrays

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, syntax-error, std, valarray

I have a strange compile error using valarrays in C++.

This is a stripped down version of my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>

using namespace std;

bool test(const int &x,const valarray<int> &a,const valarray<int> &b) {
    return a*x==b;
}

int main() {
    int a1[3]= {1,2,3};
    int b1[3]= {2,4,6};
    valarray<int> a(a1,3);
    valarray<int> b(b1,3);
    int x=2;
    cout<<test(x,a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

Expected behavior: outputs some variant of `true` or `1`

The compile error (using g++):

```
main.cpp: In function ‘bool test(const int&, const std::valarray<int>&, const std::valarray<int>&)’:
main.cpp:7:14: error: cannot convert ‘std::_Expr<std::_BinClos<std::__equal_to, std::_Expr, std::_ValArray, std::_BinClos<std::__multiplies, std::_ValArray, std::_Constant, int, int>, int>, bool>’ to ‘bool’ in return
  return a*x==b;
              ^
```

What does this compile error mean, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that comparing valarrays with `==` does not return a `bool`, it returns `std::valarray<bool>`, doing the comparison element-wise.

If you want to compare them for equality, you can call `min()` on the result, since `false < true`:

```
return (a*x==b).min();
```

Comment: Thank you! I initially thought that the `==` operator works the same way on `valarray`s and `vector`s (i.e. returns `bool`). Also, I was surprised that comparing `bool`s doesn't lead to compile errors. It's just a shame that there isn't an easier way to compare `valarray`s for equality.

Comment: This is inefficient because it doesn't short-circuit. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 5):

What prevented you from reading the documentation? `==` does not work in this way for valarrays. It compares each element index-wise and returns a new valarray of `bool`s containing each result.

Indeed, *the entire purpose* of valarrays [is to enable quick and easy operations on an ordered set of values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12580789/560648) without having to resort to writing loops everywhere.