# Best way to test for equality of two valarray<double>?

Tags: c++, valarray

I think that the default overload of `==` for `valarray` is not very convenient. By default `x==y` (for two valarrays x and y) returns a `valarray<bool>`, with `true` on the `i`th entry if `x[i]==y[i]`. Rather, I need a single `bool`, which tells me if both `valarray<double>` contain the same elements or not. I know I can do this with a cycle, but having to do the cycle every time is not convenient. What's the best workaround here? Is there a way for me to define my own overload of `==` (and also `!=`, `<`, and so on)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24628918/strange-c-compile-error-with-valarrays

Comment: do a `sum` on the `std::valarray<bool>`

Comment: @user3528438 `sum` would `and` the bools?

Comment: Would it be convenient to wrap the return value of `valarray<bool>` with `std::all_of`?

Answer (score 3):

"Not very convenient"? This behaviour is exactly the reason for `valarray`.

To override it would be entirely self-defeating.

If you don't like it, just use a `vector` instead.

Comment: I like how `x+y` works for `valarray`, and I couldn't do that if  I used `vector`. But I think `x==y` should return a single `bool`. Is there a way to modify just `==` (and the other comparisons)?

Comment: @becko: Hum just write a simple function to do it?

Comment: `+` was just an example. I also want `-`, `*`, and so on. Moreover, I know that `valarray` has contrived versions of these operators which are more efficient than a naive implementation (I think they use proxy classes to store intermediate results in expressions like `x + y + z` and then evaluate the whole expression together). I would like to take advantage of those.

Answer (score 1):

Do not override the default `operator==` use for example this instead:

```
bool isEqual( const std::valarray< bool >& aResult )
{
    bool equals = true;
    for ( auto item : aResult )
    {
        equals &= item;
    }
    return equals;
}
```

And then use it:

```
std::valarray< int > x;
std::valarray< int > y;

bool equals = isEqual( x == y );
```

Comment: If I can (can I? how?) override the default `operator==`, why not do it? That would be clearer to read than `isEqual(x==y)`.

Comment: @becko because the operator is alredy doing half of what you need. On the other hand, if `x!=y` then not all elements have to be compared. Would be interesting to see what would be faster.

Comment: @tobi303 both `x==y` and `x!=y` can short-circuit (which would be easy to fix in this answer).

Comment: @becko I did not mean the operator `!=` but the evaluation of `==` in case x is not equal to y. Of course the same works for `!=`.

Comment: @becko as I understand it, in the answer all elements are compared (by the built-in `x==y`). He only shortcircuits the AND of all this results while one could already short-circuit the comparison of the elements (but this would require not to use the built-in `==`)

Comment: There can be an `if` in the `for` loop if you like it better. And if the item is false just return false.

Comment: @p.i.g. Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: @p.i.g. yes, you can do that, but then you still compare all elements of the valarrays (before you even enter the loop), which is not the most efficient way.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the others not to override the `==` operator. The reason is that those operators are the major reason to use a `valarray`. If you do not need element-wise operators simply do not use `valarray`. Also you might need the original version of the operator at some point so why would you throw it away?

I like p.i.g s solution, but if efficiency is a major concern, I would modify it like this:

```
#include <utility>
#include <valarray>

template <typename T>
bool isEqual( const std::valarray<T>& x,const std::valarray<T>& b) {
    bool equals = true;

    for (auto it = std::make_pair(std::begin(x), std::begin(b));it.first != std::end(x);++it.first,++it.second) {
        equals &= ((*it.first) == (*it.second));
        if (!equals) break;
    }
    return equals;
}
```

and use it like this

```
valarray<T> x,y;
bool b = isEqual(x,y);
```

By not using the built-in `==` not all elements in the valarrays have to be compared.

PS:

> `+` was just an example. I also want -, *, and so on. Moreover, I know that valarray has contrived versions of these operators which are more efficient than a naive implementation (I think they use proxy classes to store intermediate results in expressions like x + y + z and then evaluate the whole expression together). I would like to take advantage of those.

Actually, thats interesting and I didnt know about this before. And the conclusion should be: Do not override those operators, otherwise you cannot take advantage of their clever implementations.

Comment: @Anakhand hum, seems like i didnt test the code at all. Shame on me. Only now I realized that the function compares the elements of the first parameter with elements of the first parameter :/

Comment: @Anakhand thanks, fixed (well still not tested tbh)

Answer (score 0):

If you are decided on "overriding" `std::valarray`'s `operator==` for commodity (instead of writing a named function like in [user463035818's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31145282/6117426)), you could write a custom "adaptor" class:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class CustomValArray : public std::valarray<T> {
public:
    typedef std::valarray<T> base;
    // We need to re-implement any non-default constructors we want to use:
    CustomValArray(std::initializer_list<T> init) : base(init) {}
};

/// Accumulation (single bool) comparison 
template<typename T>
bool operator==(const CustomValArray<T> &lhs, const CustomValArray<T> &rhs) {
    return std::equal(std::begin(lhs), std::end(lhs), std::begin(rhs));
}
```

If you also wanted to be able to use the original `operator==` for `std::valarray`, you could do so by writing a named function:

```cpp
/// Element-wise comparison
template<typename T>
auto elementWiseEqual(const CustomValArray<T> &lhs, const CustomValArray<T> &rhs)  {
    // We delegate to operator==(const std::valarray<T> &, const std::valarray<T> &)
    typedef std::valarray<T> base;
    return dynamic_cast<const base &>(lhs) == dynamic_cast<const base &>(rhs);
}
```

*Note: the snippet above uses C++14's automatic return type deduction. If you're on C++11, you should add something like `-> decltype(std::valarray<T>() == std::valarray<T>())` to the end of the declarator.*

[**Try it here.**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d9539f7bf56af12)

If you choose to do it like this, inheriting directly from `std::valarray`, be aware of the [possible risks of inheriting from an STL class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034916/is-it-okay-to-inherit-implementation-from-stl-containers-rather-than-delegate).

---

As an alternative, you could have a wrapper class with a `std::valarray<T>` private member, and manually delegate any member functions you want to use to `std::valarray`.