# How to change default `operator==` for `valarray`?

Tags: c++, stl

Can I create my own overload of `==` for `valarray<double>`? I don't like the default behavior where `x==y` (for `valarray`s `x` and `y`) returns a `valarray<bool>`. I want it to return a single `bool`, `true` if `x` and `y` have the same values.

Can I overwrite the default overload of `operator==` for `valarray<double>`.

Comment: How is this question different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31125807/best-way-to-test-for-equality-of-two-valarraydouble?

Comment: Why don´t you make just a "normal" non-operator function?

Comment: Of Course!you can provide your own overload that has more precedence, but you **can't**  overwrite the default (which you don't like it's behavior!).the trick here is to make sure that everywhere you compare valarray's, the unqualified lookup is going to find this overload.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure. You can't "overwrite the default", you but you can provide your own overload that will have higher precedence:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>

bool operator==(const std::valarray<double>& a, const std::valarray<double>& b)
{
    std::cout << "hi\n";
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::valarray<double> a, b;
    a == b; // prints hi
}
```

Since [`operator==`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/operator_cmp) is a non-member function template, a function that isn't a template will be preferred in overload resolution. The key is to make sure that everywhere you compare `valarray`'s, unqualified lookup will find this overload.

Of course, it's a lot safer to just write:

```
bool equals(const std::valarray<double>&, const std::valarray<double>&);
```

Comment: Try `equals(x + y + z, t)`, where `x`, `y`, `z` and `t` are `valarray<double>`. It won't work because `x+y+z` returns a "proxy" expression class which won't match `valarray<double>` in overload resolution. How can I fix that?