# Any easy way to implement arithmetic operations for std::array and std::vector?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, containers

Any easy way to overload all kinds of arithmetic operators (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `+=`, ...) for `std::array` and `std::vector`? The arithmetic operations are member-wise. Something like the following

```
template<class ContainerT, class opT>
ContainerT operator opT(ContainerT const& a, ContainerT const& b)
{
    ....
}

template<class ContainerT, class opT>
ContainerT operator opT=(ContainerT const& a, ContainerT const& b)
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: Well, I can tell you right now you're gonna have to overload all of them at least once.  It should be possible to achieve with just one overloading per operator though.

Comment: You mean you want to perform an operator for each element?

Comment: Are the containers supposed to be digits? 1xN or Nx1 matrices? Regardless, it isn't going to get easier than writing *code* unless you use someone else's.

Comment: it isn't clear what you want to do, do you want a map, a fold... just in place evaluation of a function... C++ gives you a lot of rope... does an array plus an int mean to add as an element or add each element?

Comment: This is what `std::valarray` is for.

Comment: You can't make the operator a template parameter, but you can use "preprocessor" macros to make each of the operators a one-liner.  For all the evils of macros, that's very safe if you use the form `#ifdef X` / `#error Macro X already defined` / ... / `#undef X`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
std::vector<int> input1(..);
std::vector<int> input2(..);
std::vector<int> output(input1.size());
std::transform (input1.begin(), input1.end(), input2.begin(), output.begin(), std::plus<int>());
```

There are other functors to choose from and you could always make your own or use a lambda.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want this?

```
#include <iostream>    // std::cout
#include <iterator>    // std::ostream_iterator, std::back_inserter
#include <algorithm>   // std::copy, std::transform
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
#include <list>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vt = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    std::deque<int> de = { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
    std::list<int> out;

    std::transform(vt.begin(), vt.end(), de.begin(), std::back_inserter(out),
        [](int a, int b) { return a + b; });

    std::copy(out.begin(), out.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

Output is:

```
4
6
8
10
12
```

---

I think operator-overload to STL container, such as `std::vector` is not good. Instead, you can use [std::valarray](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/valarray/valarray/operators/).

Comment: How is that different from `std::transform`?

Comment: @NeilKirk the input iterator range of `std::transform` is one, but my `do_operation` can perform with two ranges.

Comment: So can `std::transform`, it is overloaded.

Comment: valarrays are a little doubtful nowadays; please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602451/c-valarray-vs-vector