# Extract a subvector from a vector without copy

Tags: c++, iterator, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I have a large size of vector and I want extract its subvector based on index. But I do not want to make a new copy of a subvector.
Can I use pointer a iterator to return the pointer of the original vector?

something like:

```
vector<int> orig = { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
vector<int> index = { 3,5,6,8 };
vector<int> dest (vector<int> orig, vector<int> index) 
{
   .... 
}
```

What I want get is get dest as { 3,5,6,8 } and it is point to orig but not the new copy. 
(index is the index vector of what I want to extract from the original vector)

Or, can I use smart pointer to do this?

Comment: The problem with pointers is they'll be invalidated as soon as the vector resizes.

Comment: A vector is a contiguously stored container of elements; what you want doesn't seem to be compatible with that.

Answer (score 6):

You won't be able to create a `std::vector<T>` from a subrange of another `std::vector<T>`. However, you could travel in terms of a view which stores iterators into a `std::vector<T>` which is owning the actual values:

```
template <typename Iterator>
class array_view {
    Iterator begin_;
    Iterator end_;
public:
    // ...
    array_view(Iterator begin, Iterator end): begin_(begin), end_(end) {}
    Iterator begin() const { return this->begin_; }
    Iterator end() const   { return this->end_; }
    typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::reference
    operator[](std::size_t index) { return this->begin_[index]; }
};
```

Things get a bit interesting if you want to deal with the same type independently of who owns the actual array. In that case you might want to create something like the `array_view<T>` above but also storing a `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<T>>` for the underlying representation (and if you need to modify the original representation, you'd store offsets instead of iterators).

Answer (score 6):

Every time I say I've sworn off `std::valarray`, somebody brings up a problem like this that `valarray` supports quite directly. For example:

```
std::valarray<int> orig = { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
std::valarray<size_t> index = { 3,5,6,8 };

orig[index] = -1;
```

Then if (for example) we print out the elements of `orig` with code like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<orig.size(); i++)
    std::cout << orig[i] << "\t";
```

... we get the following results:

```
0       1       2       -1      4       -1      -1      7       -1      9
```

Comment: `valarray` looks pretty interesting! Related question comparing it with `vector`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602451/c-valarray-vs-vector

Answer (score 3):

If you want the vector to be mutable, no.  If you just want to pass a subvector around but not change the contents, why not change your various functions to take a start and end iterator rather than be passed a vector?

Comment: I didn't find a way to use iterator start and end to extract from the vector with non-continuously index. Cna you show a simple example?

Comment: No, it won't work with a gap in the list.  You could do a variation on that where you keep lists of start/end iterator pairs, but I really wouldn't suggest that level of complexity without a really good reason.