# C++11: should I use valarray or vector for numerical computing

Tags: c++11, valarray

The question of vector vs valarray has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602451/c-valarray-vs-vector).
My question refers specifically to the case of C++11. I have been reading a ["A Tour of C++"](http://www.stroustrup.com/Tour.html) and ["The C++ Programming Language"](http://www.stroustrup.com/4th.html). Both books are written by Bjarne Stroustrup. In the first book the author explains that `std::valarray` should be preferred for numerical computing (Chapter 12). But then in the second book, in chapter 29, the author implements a Matrix class in terms of a `std::vector`.

Also by doing a bit of [googling](https://hackernoon.com/c-investigation-arrays-vs-vectors-e9ba864468b6), it seems that performance-wise, a `std::vector` is just as fast as dynamically allocated "raw arrays".

So in the context of C++11, which container should be preferred for numerical computing?

My take on this would be that since `std::vector` provides fast access to its contents using the `operator[]` (which returns a reference to the data with no bounds checking) and that it is also safer to use a `std::vector` over a dynamically allocated array, `std::vector` should be preferred. 
Also, from C++11 onwards:

- `std::vector` provides direct access to the underlying data using `std::vector::data()`
- std::vector can be resized in order to use less memory using `std::vector::shrink_to_fit()`

Comment: Why don't you measure and verify which would be faster. In modern C++ world, std::vector should be used as default container unless we have reason not to do.

Answer (score 3):

valarray has the nice [functionality](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray), that you easily can apply mathematical functions element-wise and you have better slicing abilities. You can e.g. do `v3 = sin(v2 + v1*3)`

Nevertheless, if you really want to do scientific computing, consider using a library such as [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page)

Comment: I am aware of Eigen, Armadillo, MTL4 as well as the many other matrix libraries. One of the problem with these libraries is that their source code is completely opaque (in other words difficult as a learning tool, or if I wanted to change something myself). My question is also more on a conceptual basis. My understanding is that std::valarray is "unfinished business"