# Slicing a vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector, slice

Is there an equivalent of list slicing `[1:]` from Python in C++ with vectors? I simply want to get all but the first element from a vector.

Python's list slicing operator:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = list1[1:]  

print(list2) # [2, 3]
```

C++ Desired result:

```
std::vector<int> v1 = {1, 2, 3};
std::vector<int> v2;
v2 = v1[1:];

std::cout << v2 << std::endl;  //{2, 3}
```

Comment: `v2 = std::vector<int>(v1.begin() + 1, v1.end());`

Comment: @DimChtz -- make that an answer.

Comment: @juanchopanza I'll explain it in the post more

Comment: do you want to copy or reference the elements?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to extract a subvector from a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421573/best-way-to-extract-a-subvector-from-a-vector)

Comment: All these answers give no information into when it's good to use which approach and what the differences are.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

This can easily be done using `std::vector`'s copy constructor:

```
v2 = std::vector<int>(v1.begin() + 1, v1.end());
```

Comment: This answer could be improved mentioning whether `v1.end()` is included or not.

Comment: @AlessandroFlati could you explain what you mean?

Comment: Mh, trying to rephrase.
Does `v2` contain `v1.end()`, the element at the end of the first vector?

Comment: @AlessandroFlati Yes, it does. Otherwise my answer would be wrong since OP asked: "I simply want to get all but the first element from a vector" :)

Comment: I know it does, I just suggested to include it in the answer to make it flawless.

Comment: Just for the record, `v1.end()` is not the element at the end of the vector, it is the iterator that points at the (non-existent) element _after_ the last element.

Comment: Is the Time Complexity `O(size of sliced vector)` ?

Comment: @Prakhar Affirmative.

Comment: Please remove that last sentence. As @kirelagin mentioned, v1.end() does not point to the last element in the vector. So no, v2 won't contain v1.end().

Answer (score 16):

In C++20 it is pretty easy:

```
#include <span>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<int left = 0, int right = 0, typename T>
constexpr auto slice(T&& container)
{
    if constexpr (right > 0)
    {
        return std::span(begin(std::forward<T>(container))+left, begin(std::forward<T>(container))+right);
    }
    else
    {
        return std::span(begin(std::forward<T>(container))+left, end(std::forward<T>(container))+right);
    }
}



int main()
{
    std::vector v{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

    std::cout << "-------------------" << std::endl;
    auto v0 = slice<1,0>(v);
    for (auto i : v0)
    {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "-------------------" << std::endl;
    auto v1 = slice<0,-1>(v);
    for (auto i : v1)
    {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "-------------------" << std::endl;
    auto v2 = slice<1,3>(v);
    for (auto i : v2)
    {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "-------------------" << std::endl;
    auto v3 = slice<1,-1>(v);
    for (auto i : v3)
    {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "-------------------" << std::endl;
    auto v4 = slice<3,3>(v);
    for (auto i : v4)
    {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }

}
```

Result:

```
Program returned: 0
-------------------
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
-------------------
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
-------------------
2
3
-------------------
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
-------------------
```

You can also add boundary checks and other cases like negative left indices etc... but this is only an example.

Run in compiler explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/qeaxvjdbj

Comment: This slice syntax is pretty cool. But why not use `std::slice`?

Comment: std::slice is ok, but I was trying something similar to python syntax for std::vector. As I understand std::slice does not work with std::vector. (previous comment was truncated)

Answer (score 13):

It depends on whether you want a view or a copy.

Python's slicing for lists copies references to the elements, so it cannot be simply regarded as a view or a copy. For example,

```py
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = list1[1:]  
list2[1] = 5
print(list1) # does not change, still [1, 2, 3]
```

```py
list1 = [1, 2, [3]]
list2 = list1[1:]  
list2[1][0] = 5
print(list1) # changes, becomes [1, 2, [5]]
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5131563/5376789) for details.

[DimChtz's anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50549636/5376789) models the copy situation. If you just want a view, in C++20, you can use [ranges](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges) (besides [`std::views::drop`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/drop_view), [`std::views::take`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/take_view) and [`std::views::counted`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/view_counted) are also useful):

```cpp
auto v2 = v1 | std::views::drop(1); // #include <ranges>
for (auto &e: v2) std::cout << e << '\n';
```

or [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span):

```cpp
std::span v2{v1.begin() + 1, v1.end()}; // #include <span>
for (auto &e: v2) std::cout << e << '\n';
```

Comment: One can also use `std::span::subspan()` with span. It doesn’t support negative index, though.

Answer (score 7):

I know it's late but have a look at [`valarray`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray) and its [`slice`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/slice)s. If you are using a vector of some sort of `NumericType`, then it's worth giving it a try.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602451/c-valarray-vs-vector

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the above answer. It's always better to know multiple ways.

```
int main
{
    std::vector<int> v1 = {1, 2, 3};
    std::vector<int> v2{v1};
    v2.erase( v2.begin() );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would say this way of doing it is inefficient compared with the solution above, since `erase` will delete the first element and then relocate all the others. So then you first perform a copy of N elements, then delete one, then move N-1.

Comment: I never said it is efficient. I shared this as another way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

To find a sub vector from index **a** to **b**, then, simply do this:

```
vector<int> sub_vec(v.begin() + a, v.begin() + b + 1);
```

This will create a Sub Vector from the `a` index to the `b` index and we also add 1 in the end of the range while slicing as because end index will be excluded (value `b-1` will be taken as the last index). So, we add 1 to include our last index also.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the cheapest way is to use pointer to the starting element and the number of elements in the slice. It would not be a real vector but it will be good enough for many uses.

Comment: The idea is reasonable, but C++ already has this packaged as `std::span`. xskxzr added an answer showing how to use it.