# Merge sort working but deleting elements c++

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, mergesort

Okay I have fiddled around with everything and can not find the problem. I am new to c++ and really need help with this. The merge sort works perfectly but for some odd reason will not give all the values. Working with recursive merge sort can be confusing so was hoping I could have this problem solved. Thank you!1

the output when program is ran. ignore the bubble sort:
[image: the output when program is ran. ignore the bubble sort]

Here is the input from the image:
{41, 18467, 6334, 26500, 19169, 15724, 11478, 29358, 26962, 24464, 5705, 28145, 23281, 16827, 9961, 491, 2995, 11942, 4827, 5436}

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

vector <int> mergeSort(vector <int> data);

vector <int> merge(vector <int> arrayOne, vector <int> arrayTwo);

vector <int> dataList;

vector <int> dataListSorted;

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        dataList.push_back(rand());
    }

    int arrSize = dataList.size();
    cout << arrSize << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++)
    {
        cout << dataList[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;


    dataListSorted = mergeSort(dataList);

    cout << "mergeSort" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++)
    {
        cout << dataListSorted[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}   


vector <int> mergeSort(vector <int> data)
{
    int arrSize = data.size();

    if (arrSize == 1)
    {
        return data;
    }

    vector <int> arrayOne;
    vector <int> arrayTwo;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < (arrSize / 2); i++)
    {
        arrayOne.push_back(data[i]);
        arrayTwo.push_back(data[i+arrSize/2]);
    }

    arrayOne = mergeSort(arrayOne);
    arrayTwo = mergeSort(arrayTwo);

   
    return merge(arrayOne,arrayTwo);
}
   
vector <int> merge(vector <int> arrayOne, vector <int> arrayTwo)
{
    vector <int> data;

    
    while (arrayOne.size() != 0 && arrayTwo.size() != 0)
    {
        if (arrayOne[0] > arrayTwo[0])
        {
            data.push_back(arrayTwo[0]);
            arrayTwo.erase(arrayTwo.begin());
        }
        else
        {
            data.push_back(arrayOne[0]);
            arrayOne.erase(arrayOne.begin());
        }
    }

    while (arrayTwo.size() != 0)
    {
        data.push_back(arrayTwo[0]);
        arrayTwo.erase(arrayTwo.begin());
    }
    while (arrayOne.size() !=  0)
    {
        data.push_back(arrayOne[0]);
        arrayOne.erase(arrayOne.begin());
    }

    return data;
    

    
}
```

Comment: Please edit your post with the input as text.  My computer tools aren't set up to extract the numbers from the image, nor am I willing to hook up a projector to the computer to see the numbers.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews The input is random but I will edit it to include the numbers shown,

Comment: My friend, you have a strange definition of "working" if it includes sorts deleting data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < (arrSize / 2); i++)
{
    arrayOne.push_back(data[i]);
    arrayTwo.push_back(data[i+arrSize/2]);
}
```

fails to work correctly when `arrSize` is an odd number. For example, if `arrSize` is 5, then `arrSize / 2` evaluates to 2. Then, `i` takes values 0 and 1. So, `arrayOne` covers indices 0 and 1, and `arrayTwo` covers indices 0+2=2 and 1+2=3. Index 4 gets missed.

You could fix it by adding a conditional check, or using two loops. For example, you could add, after the loop

```
if (arrSize % 2 == 1) {
    arrayTwo.push_back(data[arrSize-1]);
}
```

Even better, you could [slice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50549611/5987698) the array. That is, you could remove the loop and use:

```
arrayOne = vector<int>(data.begin(), data.begin()+arrSize/2);
arrayTwo = vector<int>(data.begin()+arrSize/2, data.end());
```

Comment: Would something like using the floor function from cmath be better than just dividing? As it will always round up eliminating that error.

Comment: @Zainsiu You could, but I think using a slice (see edit) is much more concise and idiomatic.

Comment: Okay you are amazing!! Literally fixed that all for me.