# Serializing only part of an std::vector with Boost serialization

Tags: c++, boost-serialization

I have a large `std::vector<X>` where `X` is a structure with a `serialize` function for `Boost`.

I would like to serialize only part (a contiguous segment) of this vector in such a way that deserializing the result would give me an `std::vector<X>` with just the elements I serialized.

I can provide iterators pointing to the beginning and the end of the segment I want to serialize, or I can provide begin and end indices. Is there a way to do that without creating a smaller vector and copying the desired elements in it?

Note that I am using `binary archives` so any solution that would work only for this type of archive is fine.

Comment: Why iterators won't work?

Comment: How would you serialize using iterators? (I mean, aside from doing a loop myself to serialize elements one by one)

Comment: You could try it with boost ranges, but i really don't see the problem with writing one for loop (or alternatively `std::for_each`).

Answer (score 0):

Using std::valarray(https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray) is the way to go here. Coincidentally, boost serialization supports valarray as well, so you're good to go. 
Here's a comparison btw std::vector and std::valarray for clarity's sake: [C++ valarray vs. vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602451/c-valarray-vs-vector)

Comment: Since you are already suggesting data copy, what value would it add except more complexity?

Comment: Indeed, converting the original std::vector to an std::valarray would produce a copy in the first place.