# Why are std::vector and std::valarray initializing constructors different?

Tags: c++, vector, language-lawyer, std, valarray

I have just been burned by the following.

If I want to initialize a `std::vector` of `n` elements with a constant `X` I do this:

```
std::vector<double> v(n, X);
```

But if I need to initialize a `std::valarray` of `n` elements with a constant `X` I need to swap the size and initializing constant:

```
std::valarray<double> va(X, n);
```

This seems to me like an arbitrary 'gotcha'.

Is there a technical reason or some design rationale provided by the standards committee when deciding about the order of the fill constructor's parameters when `std::vector` and `std::valarray` were standardized?

Comment: `std::valarray` is a bit of a exot among the containers, I suppose many things would be different if it was added today. I remember an anwer explaining some background, lets see if I can find it

Comment: @Scheff exactly, imho [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1602787/4117728) nicely explains why `std::valarray` never was as useful as intended

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Because they don't come from the same place: `vector` comes from the STL library, and `valarray` doesn't (I haven't been able to find out where it comes from, but there seem to be strong connections to Fortran).

Quoting Bjarne himself:

> Most of the time, work on each of these components progressed in
> isolation from work on the others. There was no overall design or
> design philosophy.
> [...]
> Basically, the committee failed to contain “design by committee” so
> whereas the STL reflects a clear philosophy and coherent style, most
> of the other components suffered. Each represents its own style and
> philosophy, and some (such as `string`) manage simultaneously to present several.

(From "Evolving a language in and for the real world: C++ 1991-2006".)

So I would say that the rationale is the traditional C++ one, "things are the way they are, and changing them for the sake of Standardization would break a lot of things, so let's leave well enough alone".